# I have multiple lists, Get the largest list where the sublists in the list are not intersections

Tags: java, list, algorithm

for example：

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7);
    List<Integer> list4 = Arrays.asList(2, 3);
    List<Integer> list5 = Arrays.asList(7);
    List<Integer> list6 = Arrays.asList(3);
}
```

The result is stored with the following collection

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

i want this result,The sublists in each list in the result are disjoint,they don't need to be in order

```
[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2],[3, 4],[7]]
[[1, 2],[3],[5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2],[3],[7]]
[[2, 3],[5, 6, 7]]
[[2, 3],[7]]
```

Comment: That is unclear, please [edit] and explain more, you want combinations of lists, keeping values order ?

Comment: sorry, this is my first time asking，they don't need to be in order

Comment: I mean the ints in order. why is there not `[[3, 4],[7]]` ? what "complement each other" mean ?

Comment: Because [[1, 2],[3, 4],[7]] contains [[3, 4],[7]]，The sublists in each list in the result are disjoint,they don't need to be in order

Answer (score -2):

You can use like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
      
      list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
      list.get(0).add(12);

      System.out.println(list.get(0).get(0));
    }
}
```

for more information here is link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-collections-in-java/

Comment: Have you read the question? This is not what OP is asking.